# ¿Como implementar Jwt en apllicacion Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Estoy tratando de implementar JWT en una aplicacion, pero tengo el siguiente problema : Establesco el tiempo de expiracion de dicho token en 2 minutos entonces me logeo y obtengo el token , espero que pasen los 2 minutos y hago una peticion a mi aplicacion enviando el token pero la aplicacion de igual manera me deja acceder a los actions no niega el acceso, como puedo solucionar esto ??

Mi codigo :

StartUp.cs

```
  public class Startup
    {
        private IConfigurationBuilder builder;
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            this.builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            EngineData.DefaultConnection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ConexionDb"];
            EngineData.UrlBase = Configuration["Site:UrlBase"];
            EngineData.JwtKey = Configuration["Jwt:Key"];
            EngineData.JwtIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
            EngineData.JwtAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];

            //EntityFramework
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ShineContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConexionDb")));

            //JasonWebToken JWt
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddJwtBearer(options =>
           {
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidateAudience = true,
                   ValidateLifetime = true,
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                   ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                   ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                   IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
               };
           });
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Metodo que genera mi token

```
  private string GenerateJSONWebToken(User userInfo)
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EngineData.JwtKey));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var KClaims = new[] {
                               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userInfo.Username),
                               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, userInfo.Name),
                               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, userInfo.Email),
                               new Claim("ExpiracionToken", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2).ToString()),
                               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(EngineData.JwtKey,
              EngineData.JwtIssuer,
              claims:KClaims,
              expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2),
              signingCredentials: credentials);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

Comment: para validacion de expiracion tambien te falta la propiedad  ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero en TokenValidationParameters

Answer (score 0):

se que ya es vieja la pregunta pero por si aun te sirve, como indican necesitas el `ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero` en la clase `startup`:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidateIssuer = false,
                   ValidateAudience = false,
                   ValidateLifetime = true,
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                   IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["jwt:key"])),
                   ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
               });
```

y donde generas tu `clamis` para las cuentas de los usuarios defines el tiempo que durara la sesión:

```
 //creamos una instancia con la llave simetrica de seguridad
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:key"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            //creamos una variable para controlar la fecha de expiracion del token en esta caso sera de una hora
            var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);

            //creamos la estructura del token
            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
               issuer: null,
               audience: null,
               claims: claims,
               expires: expiration,
               signingCredentials: creds);

            //retornamos el usuariotoken y el tiempo de expiracion
            return new UserToken()
            {
                Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                Expiration = expiration
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

Tus endpoints deben contar con el filtro **[Authorize]** a nivel de Action o Controller, en caso estes usando roles debes usar **[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]**.

Comment: Si agrego la etiqueta [Authorize] me dice NO autorizado

Comment: ¿Tienes dos apis?, ¿uno de autenticación y otro para las consultas?, si es asi, ambos deben compartir la misma llave indicada en tu **appsettings**, indicada en la linea **IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))**

Comment: No es la misma APi